# It's too slow to show image sequence as a video in Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, loader

At first I'm a new Flex AS programmer. My need is the same as @Michael Pliskin [Best way to show image sequence as a movie in Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702743/best-way-to-show-image-sequence-as-a-movie-in-adobe-air/703663#703663), but I need show image sequence to animate video in browser through Flash Player. In the @Michael's post, CookieOfFortune gave us an advice as:

> You could have an image control as your movie frame, then load up a buffer of BitmapData objects. Fill the BitmapData objects with the images as they come in, and then call the image load function to load the next image in the buffer.

As CookieOfFortune's advice, what's the complete code? 
  After reading Adobe AS3.0 online docs and book "Essential ActionScript3.0", I wrote codes as following idea:
  1.A TCP server with Java language to send all jgp files(totally 6697 files about 2 minutes), each file with two bytes file length data prefix 
  2.A flex AS3.0 class DisplayAssetLoader extends Sprite in which connects the TCP server to receive all binary bytes. 
  3.A timer with 50ms(20 frames/sec) intervals in class DisplayAssertLoader to render the bytes got from TCP server 
  Everything is OK but the jpg images playing speed is very very slow in IE10. Is that my codes anything wrong? Or is any other ways to play jpg sequence as a movie? I'm very thankful if somebody gives complete code.  
 All code is here:
1.Java code snippet: TCP Server to send jpg file with binary

```java
            // 
            // --- ...accept socket connections (blocks until a
            // connection
            // is made)
            socket = server.accept();

            // --- create the output stream
            ps = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            for (int i = 1; i < 6697; i++) {
                String fileName = "D:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/workspace/JPGFilerServer/bin/jpg/image" + i + ".jpg";

                //read the file in to our byte array
                readfile(fileName);                         

                // --- write the bytes and close the connection
                ps.write(bytes);
                System.out.println("====write a file: image"+i+", OK, bytes="+bytes.length);

            }
```

2.Flex AS script as a image play client:

```AS
    package { 
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class DisplayAssetLoader extends Sprite  {
    [source="spritesheets/browncollector.png"]
    public var BrownCollector:Class;

    // A constant representing the ASCII character for "end of transmission"
    public static const EOT:int = 4;
    // An on-screen TextField in which to display status messages
    private var statusField:TextField;
    // The socket object over which communication will occur
    private var socket:Socket;
    // A byte buffer in which to store the asset's binary data as it loads
    private var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    // The Loader object used to generate the asset from 
    // the loaded binary data
    private var loader:Loader;

    private var timer:Timer;

    // Class constructor
    public function DisplayAssetLoader () {
        trace("sandbox type:" + Security.sandboxType);

        // Now, create the Loader object that will generate  
        // the asset from the loaded bytes
        loader = new Loader();

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, 
            assetInitListener);

        timer = new Timer(50,0);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerEvent);
        // Create the status TextField
        statusField = new TextField();
        statusField.border     = true;
        statusField.background = true;
        statusField.width = statusField.height = 350;
        statusField.x=300;
        statusField.y=0;
        addChild(statusField);

        // Create the socket object
        socket = new Socket();

        // Register for socket events
        socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectListener);
        socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeListener);
        socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, 
            socketDataListener);
        socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);

        // Tell the user we're about to try connecting to the socket      
        out("Attempting connection...");  

        timer.start();

        // Attempt to connect to the socket
        try {
            socket.connect("localhost", 7777);
        } catch (e:Error) {
            out("Connection problem!\n");
            out(e.message);
        }
    }

    protected function timerEvent(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        if (buffer.length<1) return;


        renderImg();
        event.updateAfterEvent();

    }

    // Handles socket connection events
    private function connectListener (e:Event):void {
        out("Connected! Waiting for data...");
    }

    // Handles newly received data
    private function socketDataListener (e:ProgressEvent):void {

        // When new bytes arrive, store them in a buffer for later processing
        socket.readBytes(buffer, buffer.length, socket.bytesAvailable);

    }

    //bytes position to show in bytearray, and current file number to show
    private var curPos:int =0,fileNo:int=1;

    private function renderImg():void
    {
        //  get a file's length
        buffer.position = curPos ;
        var fileLen:int = buffer.readUnsignedByte();

        fileLen = (fileLen*256 )+ buffer[curPos+1];

        //if data is a complete file
        if(buffer.length  < (fileLen +2)*fileNo) return ;

        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        buffer.position = curPos+2;//omit two prefix byte
        buffer.readBytes(bytes ,0 ,fileLen);


        // Generate an asset from the loaded bytes
        loader.loadBytes(bytes);

        //point to the next file
        curPos += fileLen + 2;
        fileNo++;           

        out("========= rendered the file "+fileNo+" OK, len="+fileLen);
    }



    // Puts the asset on screen when it's done initializing
    private function assetInitListener (e:Event):void {

        addChild(loader.content);
        out("Asset initialzed.");
    }

    /**
     *  Handles the timer
     */
    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        renderImg();

    }

    // Handles socket disconnection events. When a disconnection occurs,
    // attempt to generate a display asset from the loaded bytes
    private function closeListener (e:Event):void {

    }
    public function clearBuffer():void {
        buffer.clear();
        out("Clear buffer.............");
    }

    // Handles I/O errors
    private function ioErrorListener (e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        out("I/O Error: " + e.text);
    }

    // Print status messages to the screen and the debugging console
    private function out (msg:*):void {
        trace(msg);
        statusField.appendText(msg + "\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: First, `Timer` is never going to be fast or accurate enough for your needs.  Replace it with `ENTER_FRAME` event, and manage your update intervals with `flash.utils.getTimer()`.  Secondly, the biggest performance hit is likely the phase of Flash rendering the bitmaps to the screen.  You could pre-buffer those offscreen (http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2080).  That said, since they're not just a few images, but a rather long string of frames, implement a worker thread (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html), for decompression/rasterizing.

Comment: Thanks @Atriace, I have tried ENTER_FRAME event, but no better improvement. As you said, the performance hit is the rendering,so I will try pre-buffer, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution that worked for your image sequence approach or did you switch to video?

Comment: @Atriace Yes, problem resolved using image sequence approach.